# Use libvlc log_set_file with Python bindings

Tags: python, linux, libvlc

How can I use libvlc's `Instance.log_set_file` function from Python bindings?

Using `open` or `os.open` like this:

```py
import vlc

instance = vlc.Instance()
f = open("/tmp/vlc.log", "w")
instance.log_set_file(f)
```

fails with:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: TypeError: expected LP_FILE instance instead of _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

A Windows specific solution can be found at the end of [this post](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=131018#p455849). I did not test if that works because I'm on Linux.

Here is a Unix specific solution that works on my system:

```
import cpython
import vlc

libc = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6')
fdopen = libc.fdopen
fdopen.restype = vlc.FILE_ptr

instance = vlc.Instance()
logfile = open(LOGFILE, 'w')
fileptr = fdopen(logfile.fileno(), 'w')
instance.log_set_file(fileptr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got this to work on my Windows computer. By slightly modifying the code block at the bottom of menew's post on the [videolan thread](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=131018#p455849) that user2804197 linked, I was able to change the libvlc logfile to "out.log" by executing this code:

```py
import ctypes
import vlc

instance = vlc.Instance()

fopen = ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.fopen
fopen.restype = vlc.FILE_ptr
fopen.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p)
f = fopen(b'out.log', b'w')

instance.log_set_file(f)
```

Notably, I changed this line

```py
f = fopen('out.log', 'w')
```

to

```py
f = fopen(b'out.log', b'w')
```

I got the idea to make this change from matteobarbieri's post [here](https://github.com/sergiomsilva/alpr-unconstrained/issues/73#issuecomment-526508256).

Here is my configuration:

- Windows 10 Home 19044.2965
- Python 3.10.8
- python-vlc 3.0.18122
- VLC 3.0.18.0 (64-bit version)